# Cypress.js environment variables - CircleCI

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, circleci, cypress

I have tests that run fine locally. My env variables are in a `cypress.json` file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "TEST_URL": "...",
    "USER_EMAIL": "...",
    "USER_PWD": "..."
  }
}
```

and in circleci, I have the env vars set with the `CYPRESS_` prefix.

The problem is when I run the tests on circle, it seems to be using the environment variable name and not the value. Here's the error I get:

```
CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:

CYPRESS_TEST_URL

We failed looking for this file at the path:

/root/app/CYPRESS_TEST_URL

The internal Cypress web server responded with:

> 404: Not Found
```

I can't see anything obviously wrong. The tests run fine locally. This is what it seems to be failing on:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('stagingLogin', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('TEST_URL'));

    cy.url()
      .should('include', 'users/sign_in');

    cy.get('input[name="user[email]"]')
      .type(Cypress.env('USER_EMAIL'))
      .should('have.value', Cypress.env('USER_EMAIL'));

    cy.get('input[name="user[password]"]')
      .type(Cypress.env('USER_PWD'))
      .should('have.value', Cypress.env('USER_PWD'));

    cy.contains('Log in')
      .click();
})
```

Comment: Are these actual (Linux/shell) env vars, or are they just an internal construct in this software?

Comment: Can you show your circle ci env config?